# Automapper IncludeMembers with List Member

Tags: automapper

```cs
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<Book> RelatedBooks { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

I have those class and I am doing this:

```
        CreateMap<Book, BookDto>()
                .IncludeMembers(s => s.RelatedBooks);
```

But I am getting

```
Missing map from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Book] to BookDto. Create using CreateMap<IEnumerable`1, BookDto>,
```

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

Desired Output without AM is something like this:

```
 public List<BookDto> GetAllBooks()
    {
        var listBookAll = new List<Book>(); // Imagine this is coming from an API

        var bookParent = listBookAll.Select(s => new BookDto
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            Title = s.Title,
        });
        var relatedBooks = listBookAll.SelectMany(s => s.RelatedBooks).Select(s2 =>
            new BookDto
            {
                Id = s2.Id,
                Title = s2.Title
            });

        var finalBooks = new List<BookDto>();
        finalBooks.AddRange(bookParent);
        finalBooks.AddRange(relatedBooks);
        return finalBooks;
    }
```

Comment: What's the desired mapping? In C#, without AM.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - I updated the post to include the desired output i was looking for. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

`IncludeMembers` doesn't help.

```
    c.CreateMap<Book, BookDto>();
    c.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Book>, List<BookDto>>().ConvertUsing((s, d, c)=>s.SelectMany(b=>b.RelatedBooks.Prepend(b)).Select(c.Mapper.Map<BookDto>).ToList());
```

and call it like this

```
    mapper.Map<List<BookDto>>(books);
```